# MS Word - change title of Table of Contents

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I'm trying to create this by not using the two standard options as I only one Heading 1 style, but using the Custom Table of Contents I am unable to choose the Title (ie "Table of Contents") and instead there is no title.  Can this be changed?

This is MS Office 2013

Answer (score 1):

No, if you insert a custom TOC, you must manually type the title (heading) and apply the appropriate paragraph style to it (e.g., **TOC Heading**).

However, if you're adamant that the heading should be automatically inserted, there's an alternative (but it's much more work). If you want the TOC to include just Heading 1 paragraphs but to otherwise look exactly like one of Word's default TOC styles, you can insert a TOC in that default style, select the TOC, right-click, click **Toggle Field Codes**, and then edit the field code directly so that it specifies that the TOC should include just 1 level (for example, change `"1-3"` in the field definition to `"1-1"`). Then press <kbd>F9</kbd> to update the field. In the **Update Table of Contents** dialog box, select **Update entire table**, and then click **OK**.

If you're not that proficient or comfortable manually editing field codes, you can select the field code (while it's still toggled, as described above), right-click, click **Edit Field**, and then, in the **Field** dialog box that opens, click the **Table of Contents** button. Then, in the **Table of Contents** dialog box, you can set the **Show levels** field to **1**. When you click **OK**, you'll be asked whether you want to replace the current TOC. Click **Yes**.

In both cases, the TOC should now show just 1 level but should retain the heading that's part of the default TOC style. Changes that you make to the TOC definition in this way will be retained if you later update the TOC.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Custom Table of Contents and add your own heading using the **TOC Heading style** for your heading.

### Then, select your title and your TOC and save it to your TOC Gallery.

I would suggest the name _MyTOC in the dialog.
[image: screenshot of dialog]

This will put it at the top of the gallery next time you go to insert a Table of Contents.